# What is the formal proof of AA similarity test?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

It is a well-known fact that if any two triangles are equiangular then their sides are proportional and converse. But I am not sure how to prove it by using plane geometry only without using trigonometry, vectors, etc. Please help.

I want to use only the tools of Euclidean geometry.

Comment: You have said that you don't want to use trigonometry, vectors, or "etc", but you haven't said what you *do* want to use. "Pure geometry" is a vague category.

Comment: @MishaLavrov I have edited my question. Is it fine?

Answer (score 0):

Given : Triangles ABC and DEF with $\angle A=\angle D$,  $\angle B=\angle E$ and  $\angle C=\angle F$

Step 1:

Construction:

Take the points P and Q on AB and AC such that $AP=DE$ and $AQ=DF$

Step 2:

$AP=DE$

$\angle A=\angle D$

$AQ=DF$

$\triangle APQ\cong \triangle DEF$ (SAS)

Hence $\angle P=\angle E$ and $\angle Q=\angle F$

Step 3:

$PQ\parallel BC$ (converse, corresponding angles, $\angle P=\angle B$ and $\angle Q=\angle C$)

Step 4:

$\frac {AP}{AB}= \frac {AQ}{AC}$ (Converse, Proportionally Theorem, $PQ\parallel BC$)

and

$\frac {DE}{AB}= \frac {DF}{AC}$ (AP=DE and AQ=DF)

Step 5:

Similirly by constructing points on the other sides of triangle ABC

$\frac{DE}{AB}=\frac{DF}{AC}=\frac{EF}{BC}$

Comment: The backbone of this proof is 'proportionally theorem'. But I am taught the proof of this theorem based on similar triangles, it means I am stuck in an infinite loop. Can you please supply proof of this theorem independent of similar triangles?

Comment: I have no issue with the choice of triangles. My concern is for the usage of 'proportionally theorem'. If we are using this theorem to prove that the sides of equiangular triangles' sides are proportional then we have to prove this theorem otherwise. In simple words, what is the proof of 'proportionally theorem'?

Comment: [Basic proportionality theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intercept_theorem) is *not* proved using similarity of triangles. See the proof in the link.

Comment: However it is indeed true that proportionality theorem is equivalent to similar triangles with some constructions. Other way, two similar triangles can be oriented anyhow in plane. One can always rotate one of the triangles to align it's sides parallel to the other triangle. After this proportionality theorem again applies.

Comment: To prove Proportionally theorem,  it can be use relation between area of triangles